# Using `diag()` Command to Construct Circulant Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

Here is the question:
   Write a MATLAB program which uses the diag command to generate n by n circulant matrices: given vector v = (v1 v2 v3 ....vn). Example of circulant matrices:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5;
     5 1 2 3 4;
     4 5 1 2 3;
     3 4 5 1 2;
     2 3 4 5 1]
```

note the wrap-around patter of successive rows.
Use `diag command in MATLAB`.

(here is what I started from, I am having trouble to construct the matrix using `diag` command. Please help).

```
n = length(v);
a = zeros(n);

for i = 1:n
```

Comment: I think @Divakar has nailed down the `diag` approach, but `toeplitz` makes this a one-liner (`toeplitz(circshift(flipud(v(:)),1),v)`), although I don't think you'd get any credit from your Prof. for that answer. :D

Comment: @chappjc Yeah we all have to go through the "Prof-ways"!

Comment: BTW: This matrix is a built-in: `gallery('circul',1:5)` chappjc was close, as the implementation actually uses `toeplitz`.

Comment: @knedlsepp, Just to give the whole information, the actual doe is in the function `circul()` (Enter `edit circul.m`).

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, since [all the circulant matrices are made diagonal by the DFT](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/matrix/special.html), you can also do something like that

```
// given vector
v = [1 2 3 4 5];
n = numel(v);
// DFT matrix
F = dftmtx(n);
//circulant matrix
V = (F*diag(fft(v))*F')./n;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
%%// Given vector v
v = [1 2 3 4 5];

%%// Parameters
n = numel(v);
arr1 = [v1(2:end) v1];

%%// Construct circulant matrix
A1 = zeros(n);
for k = -(n-1):n-1
    A1 = A1+ arr1(k+n)*diag(ones(n-abs(k),1),k);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function m = prgrm9( x )
%UNTITLED3 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

m = diag(x(1)* ones(1,length(x)));

for i = 2: length(x)
   m = m + diag(x(i) * ones(1, length(x)-(i-1)),i-1)+ diag(x(i)*ones(1,i-1),i-(length(x)+1));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this without any looping is to take advantage of the Fourier properties of circulant matrices and use the FFT:

```
V = ifft( fft( diag( fft(x) ), [], 1 ), [], 2 );
```